# Releasing references to deferred: what's the point

Tags: python, twisted

This pattern is mentioned in the [Twisted tutorial](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1778) as a standard way to avoid firing the same deferred twice:

```
class A(ClientFactory):
...
def finished(self, result):
  if self.deferred is not None:
    d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
    d.callback(result)
```

But from what I understand, Deferred won't let you (i.e., raise an exception if you do) call the same instance twice. So why recreate that safety mechanism by repeating this code everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, a second call to `Deferred.callback` will raise an `AlreadyCalledError`.  It is idiomatic to write code that doesn't trigger this exception, though.  Most Deferred-using code I've written or read tries to reserve `AlreadyCalledError` to indicate programming errors rather than normal runtime conditions that can safely be ignored.

So:

```
def finished(self, result):
    try:
        self.deferred.callback(result)
    except AlreadyCalledError:
        pass
```

is not the preferred spelling.  I think this is because there might be other reasons `AlreadyCalledError` is raised that don't just stem from `finished` being called more than one and this kind of error handling would obscure those cases, potentially hiding bugs.

A second reason to throw away the `Deferred` instance is to help with unexpected exception logging.  When a `Deferred` is garbage collected and it has an unhandled `Failure` result, this `Failure` is logged.  This often indicates a programming error.  The `Deferred` can't be garbage collected as long as there are any references to it, though, so throwing away the reference in the factory at least ensures the factory won't keep the `Deferred` alive (though application code which is using the `Deferred` still could).

An alternate approach could be to write this:

```
def finished(self, result):
    if self.deferred is not None:
        self.deferred.callback(result)
        self.deferred = None
```

This still throws away the `Deferred` but without the tuple unpacking.  However, there's a problem here.

Consider a more complete version of `A`:

```
class A(ClientFactory):
    def waitUntilFinished(self):
        self.deferred = Deferred()
        return self.deferred

    def finished(self, result):
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.callback(result)
```

As you can see, it is not safe to call `A.waitUntilFinished` two times before `finished` has happened once.  That is, if you write:

```
a = A()
x = a.waitUntilFinished()
y = a.waitUntilFinished()
```

Then you can be pretty certain `x` will never receive a result.  This is perhaps sad, but you could reasonably document it as a limitation on of the API.

Now, consider this slightly different usage pattern:

```
a = A()
x = a.waitUntilFinished()

def doSomething(result):
    return a.waitUntilFinished()
x.addCallback(doSomething)
```

This code no longer calls `waitUntilFinished` twice before `finished` is called even once.  It waits until `finished` is called before calling `waitUntilFinished` a second time.  If you documented the API as only being safe to call once until the resulting Deferred fires, someone might think this usage is reasonable.

With the simpler implementation:

```
def finished(self, result):
    if self.deferred is not None:
        self.deferred.callback(result)
        self.deferred = None
```

there's a problem.  `doSomething` is called as a result of `self.deferred.callback(result)`.  More specifically, `doSomething` is called before `self.deferred.callback` returns (put another way, `doSomething` is called synchronously by that statement).  `doSomething` calls `waitUntilFinished` which creates a new `Deferred` and assigns it to the factory's `deferred` attribute.  Then `self.deferred.callback(result)` finishes and self.deferred = None`runs - and that new`Deferred` is thrown away, never to be called.

By setting `self.deferred` to `None` **before** invoking its callback chain, this case is avoided.